# Cannot export from Rstudo into Excel as a CSV. What am i doing wrong? Error message below:

Tags: r

```r
xxx <-lapply(x, zipRadius, 2)

write.csv(xxx, file = "C:/Users/John.Doe/OneDrive - TMP Worldwide Advertising & Communications, LLC/Desktop",sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 25, 55, 28, 124, 122, 99, 17, 125, 16, 113, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 43, 22, 10, 45, 41, 15, 21, 14, 18, 19, 11, 209, 265, 266, 263, 212, 29, 32, 23, 37, 38, 30, 12, 40, 20, 44, 13, 36, 24, 26, 35, 31, 34, 246, 81, 52, 53, 82, 42
In addition: Warning message:
In write.csv(xxx, file = "C:/Users/john.doe/OneDrive - TMP Worldwide Advertising & Communications, LLC/Desktop",  :
  attempt to set 'sep' ignored
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The output of `lapply` is a `list` and not a data.frame or matrix.  According to `?write.csv`, the input 'x' should be

> x - the object to be written, preferably a matrix or data frame. If not, it is attempted to coerce x to a data frame.

Based on the output from `zipRadius` (using valid 'zipcodes'), it is a `list` of `data.frame`.

```
library(ZipRadius)
out <- lapply(c("30316", "30318"), zipRadius, radius = 10)
```

structure of the `list`

```
> str(out)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   50 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ zip      : chr [1:50] "30002" "30021" "30030" "30032" ...
  ..$ city     : chr [1:50] "Avondale Estates" "Clarkston" "Decatur" "Decatur" ...
  ..$ state    : chr [1:50] "GA" "GA" "GA" "GA" ...
  ..$ latitude : num [1:50] 33.8 33.8 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
  ..$ longitude: num [1:50] -84.3 -84.2 -84.3 -84.3 -84.3 ...
  ..$ Distance : num [1:50] 5.26 8.07 3.97 4.26 6.55 5.92 7.46 7.74 8.83 5.61 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   105 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ zip      : chr [1:105] "30002" "30009" "30023" "30030" ...
  ..$ city     : chr [1:105] "Avondale Estates" "Alpharetta" "Alpharetta" "Decatur" ...
  ..$ state    : chr [1:105] "GA" "GA" "GA" "GA" ...
  ..$ latitude : num [1:105] 33.8 33.8 33.8 33.8 33.8 ...
  ..$ longitude: num [1:105] -84.3 -84.5 -84.5 -84.3 -84.3 ...
  ..$ Distance : num [1:105] 9.94 4.51 4.51 8.27 8.98 4.51 7.25 7.63 7.43 9.74 ...
```

Therefore, we can `rbind` those `list` elements to a single dataset

```
outdat <- do.call(rbind, out)
> str(outdat)
'data.frame':   155 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ zip      : chr  "30002" "30021" "30030" "30032" ...
 $ city     : chr  "Avondale Estates" "Clarkston" "Decatur" "Decatur" ...
 $ state    : chr  "GA" "GA" "GA" "GA" ...
 $ latitude : num  33.8 33.8 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
 $ longitude: num  -84.3 -84.2 -84.3 -84.3 -84.3 ...
 $ Distance : num  5.26 8.07 3.97 4.26 6.55 5.92 7.46 7.74 8.83 5.61
```

---

The documentation in the package is unclear.  As there are 3 digit or 4 digit or 5 digit zip code for US, it is possible that the function takes only 5 digit.  We could change the zip codes to a single 5 digit by appending 0s at the beginning where they are 4 or 3 to keep it standardized

```
x <- c("602", "604", "612", "613", "614", "617", "623", "627", "637", 
"641", "646", "659", "662", "664", "667", "669", "674", "676", 
"683", "685")
x1 <- sprintf('%05d', as.integer(x))
```

Now, we apply the function

```
out1 <- lapply(x1, zipRadius, radius = 10)
```

-structure

```
> str(out1)
List of 20
 $ :'data.frame':   7 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ zip      : chr [1:7] "00602" "00603" "00604" "00605" ...
  ..$ city     : chr [1:7] "Aguada" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" ...
  ..$ state    : chr [1:7] "PR" "PR" "PR" "PR" ...
  ..$ latitude : num [1:7] 18.4 18.4 18.5 18.5 18.3 ...
  ..$ longitude: num [1:7] -67.2 -67.1 -67.1 -67.1 -67.1 ...
  ..$ Distance : num [1:7] 0 6.62 9.8 7.48 5.94 6.39 4.15
 $ :'data.frame':   8 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ zip      : chr [1:8] "00602" "00603" "00604" "00605" ...
  ..$ city     : chr [1:8] "Aguada" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" ...
  ..$ state    : chr [1:8] "PR" "PR" "PR" "PR" ...
  ..$ latitude : num [1:8] 18.4 18.4 18.5 18.5 18.5 ...
  ..$ longitude: num [1:8] -67.2 -67.1 -67.1 -67.1 -67 ...
  ..$ Distance : num [1:8] 9.8 3.49 0 2.36 7.81 8.95 2.52 2.6
...
```

We get a single dataset by `rbind`ing

```
outdat2 <- do.call(rbind, out1)
> str(outdat2)
'data.frame':   168 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ zip      : chr  "00602" "00603" "00604" "00605" ...
 $ city     : chr  "Aguada" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" "Aguadilla" ...
 $ state    : chr  "PR" "PR" "PR" "PR" ...
 $ latitude : num  18.4 18.4 18.5 18.5 18.3 ...
 $ longitude: num  -67.2 -67.1 -67.1 -67.1 -67.1 ...
 $ Distance : num  0 6.62 9.8 7.48 5.94 6.39 4.15 9.8 3.49 0 ...
```

Comment: @user16760437 can you show the `str(xxx)` after the step of `data.frame(..`

Comment: You want me to add str(xxx) after data.frame(?? so: xxx <- data.frame(str(xxx),lapply(x, zipRadius, 2)))

Comment: @user16760437 yes, as you didn't show an example reproducible for testing.

Comment: @user16760437, **no**, add the output from `str(xxx)` after you created it with `data.frame(.)`. Don't put `str(xxx)` *inside* `data.frame(.)`.

Comment: @user16760437 also, can you specify the packages used i.e. `zipRadius` and what is the object `x` is it a data.frame

Comment: When i put str(xxx) it just shows the output for each of the zip code 

$ : tibble [0 x 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ zip      : chr(0) 
  ..$ city     : chr(0) 
  ..$ state    : chr(0) 
  ..$ latitude : chr(0) 
  ..$ longitude: chr(0) 
  ..$ Distance : num(0)

Comment: also, "x" is a character

Comment: That implies you are getting 0 rows.  Please consider to update your post with a small reproducible example. i.e. `dput(head(x, 20))` along with the packages used

Comment: dput(head(x, 20))
c("602", "604", "612", "613", "614", "617", "623", "627", "637", 
"641", "646", "659", "662", "664", "667", "669", "674", "676", 
"683", "685")

Comment: @user16760437 the first argument to `zipRadius` is `zipcode`.  Based on your dput, it doesn't look like valid zip codes

Comment: @user16760437 I get error with `> zipRadius("602", 10)#
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 44336, 0`

Comment: According to the documentation in the package, these are zipcodes from US.  and US zip codes to my knowlege is 5 digit

Comment: so some zips are 3, 4, and 5 digits

Comment: @user16760437 may be that function have some limitations i.e. it may only with certain zip code

Comment: When i ran  xxx <- data.frame(lapply(x, zipRadius, 2)) the function worked; however when i want to export that output i cannot. ALl i want to do is OUTPUT the data to excel

Comment: should i substitute c("30316", "30318") with x or c(x)?

Comment: @user16760437 please look at my update in the last part i.e. `x <- c("602", "604", "612", "613", "614", "617", "623", "627", "637", 
"641", "646", "659", "662", "664", "667", "669", "674", "676", 
"683", "685");
x1 <- sprintf('%05d', as.integer(x))` and then I am using `out1 <- lapply(x1, zipRadius, radius = 10)` and then `outdat <- do.call(rbind, out1)`

Comment: I have a list of 5000 zipcodes, I cannot manually input them. That is why i have "x" it is the column from excel where the 5000 zip codes come from

Comment: @user16760437 If you look at my example, I was just converting your `x` to `x1` with `sprintf`.  With your column from dataset, it is `sprintf("%05d", as.integer(yourdf$yourcol))`

Comment: it does not solve how do i output the data?

Comment: @user16760437 sorry, I don't understand what the problem is.  You have an object named `x` created in your console.  Now, only thing you need is `x1 <- sprintf("%05d", as.integer(x))` and do `xxx <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x1, zipRadius, radius = 10))`

Comment: Hi sorry, turns out my coworker needs the lists to be exported. Is this possible in R? Basically the script above prints out a lost of each zip with the 2 mile radius. You told me to rbind it into a single data frame. Is it possible to export each individual list to excel?

Comment: @user16760437 you may write the `list` elements as sheets in an excel file. i..e if the list is `lst1` `library(openxlsx); names(lst1)  <- x1; write.xlsx(lst1)`

Comment: @user16760437 if this works, please consider to accept solution.  Thanks